# Is there like a procedure/recipe to construct dense spaces (of functions) in other spaces (of functions)?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, approximation-theory

I am going back and forth in Rudin's Real and complex analysis.
One thing that I wonder is if there's like a general way to construct dense spaces in other spaces.

For example there're a lot of approximations theorems in the book, like any measurable function can be arbitrarily approximated by a continuous function with compact support or functions with compact supports are dense in $L^p(X)$.

I was however wondering if it is possible to do similar things for differentiable functions. Like is there any function space of differentiable functions dense in $L^p$ maybe?

A related question is this one I think : [Boundedness of smooth functions approximating an Lp function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1421901/boundedness-of-smooth-functions-approximating-an-lp-function)

I think however I wonder : 1) where is that result coming from and 2) can I fix say $C^k$ ($k < \infty$) rather than $C^{\infty}$

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand what you're looking for in the first question.  Are you looking for a reference for the proof that $C^\infty$ is dense in $L^p$?  And I'm not sure I understand what you are asking in the second one.  $C^\infty \subset C^k$ for all $k$, so density of $C^\infty$ implies density of $C^k$.

Comment: I have a proof that $C_c(X)$ (continuous with compact support) is dense in $L^p(X)$. I wonder if such result can be extended to say $C_c^k(X)$. I also wonder if given a source space (say $X$) and a "target one" (say $Y$) there's some procedure well known to transform somewhat $X$ into a dense subspace of $Y$ through some isomorphism or similar (a bit like when you want to embed a metric space into a complete one).

Comment: Also $C^{\infty}$ is not dense in $L^p$ cause it's not even a subset in general.